# Can't get the hour and minute from TimePicker

Tags: android

I take a time from gui control 'TimePicker' and i try to set this time on object 
type 'Calendar' that i get from Intent ( used Serializable ).

on the method 'public void doneBtnClickEvent(View view) ' 
i get an exception on the line '_calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, _timePicker.getHour());'

I don't understand what i did wrong and how to solve the problem.

```
public class SetTimeActivicy extends AppCompatActivity {

private TimePicker  _timePicker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_time_activicy);

    _timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    _timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

}

public void doneBtnClickEvent(View view) {

    try {

        // exception !! => cant take the Hour and the min
        int h = _timePicker.getHour();
        int m = _timePicker.getMinute();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception - Error ", e.getMessage());
    }



}
```

}

Comment: The exception is an NPE?

Comment: Null pointer exception ..

Comment: no, there is no null ptr ref. i just can't get the time from the _timePicker

Comment: this return unknown exception - can't catch with the try .. catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ... i use this

```
 int hour = _timePicker.getCurrentHour();
 int minute = _timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

the method

```
int h = _timePicker.getHour();
int m = _timePicker.getMinute();
```

are just not working